# How to get the value from Generic<T> in foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, function, generics, foreach

I have created one function (Generic) which supports all class model. but i have a query with respect to get the value of generic in for each loop.

This is for ASP.NET (MVC), Created code in controller.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetGenericList<T> (list<T> genModel)
{
List<SelectListItem> lst =  new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var dyn in lst)
{
    lst.add (new selectlistitem
    {
        text = dyn.??,
        Value = dyn.??
    });
}
```

}

1. if i pass employee class model to this funtion, i want to access the attributename like empid for "text" and empname for "value".
2. if i pass student class model to this function, i want to access the attribute name like studentid for "text" and studentname for "value".

Comment: Where have you used `genModel`?

Comment: You dont need Generics for this. You can create a Interface called IModelInterface (or something like this..) with Id and Name properties. Implement that interface in your classes (Student and Employee).

Pass the interface parameter to GetList method. While looping, you will just use dyn.Id and dyn.Name

Comment: `SelectListItem` have properties `Text` and `Value`, what is your problem?

Comment: Also, make sure the code you have provided will compile.

Comment: Also, your `foreach` will not run even one loop.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is to add two more parameters to your method - a text selector and a value selector:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetGenericList<T> (list<T> genModel, Func<T, string> textSelector, Func<T, string> valueSelector)
{
    List<SelectListItem> lst =  new List<SelectListItem>();
    // loop through genModel, not lst!
    foreach(var model in genModel)
    {
        lst.add (new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = textSelector(model), // Note how we use the selectors here
            Value = valueSelector(model)
        });
    }
    return lst;
}
```

To use this method with, say `Employee`, you do it like this:

```
GetGenericList(someEmployeeList, x => x.empid, x => x.empname);
```

For `Student`, you could dp:

```
GetGenericList(someStudentList, x => x.studentid, x => x.studentname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to implement [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) for this requirement. All you have to do is to have a default "broker" between your classes.

Just create a common interface for your Models

```
interface IModelInterface
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And your class should implement the Interface as

```
    public class Student : IModelInterface
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : IModelInterface
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And slight changes to your GetGenericList method

```
 public List<SelectListItem> GetListItems(List<IModelInterface> genModel)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var dyn in genModel)
        {
            lst.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = dyn.Name,
                Value = Convert.ToString(dyn.Id)
            });
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

There are multiple ways to implement this. I just gave you one of those answers.